# On mouse click, hide the link and show

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When the mouse click, I need to hide the link and show another div.

```
<div class="fetch-from-link">
 <a href="#" class="test" onClick="$(this).parent().hide();">
  Fetch from link
</a>

<div class="hello">Hello world</div>
</div>
```

I just use simple hide method. But how can I show my "hello" div after the link hide?

Comment: How would do you expect a user to show it if you hide the element that they need to click?

Comment: You are hiding the div containing your Hello world. Move it out of there or move it out when you hide the parent div with jquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following code:

```js
$(function() {
  $('.test').click(function() {
    $('.test').hide();
    $('.hello').show();
  });
})
```

```css
.hello {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="fetch-from-link">
  <a href="#" class="test">Fetch from link</a>
  <div class="hello">Hello world</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. How can I hide another element when click this same link?

Comment: You duplicate this line $('.test').hide(); and change the selector (instead of .test, use a selector that matches your element).

Answer (score 3):

Since jQuery is used bind the event handler using it instead of ugly inline click handler.

You need to `hide()` the current element, then [Class Selector ('.hello')](https://api.jquery.com/class-selector/) can be used to display the other div.

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $('.test').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).hide();
    $('.hello').show();
  })
});
```

```css
.hello {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="fetch-from-link">
  <a href="#" class="test">Fetch from link</a>
  <div class="hello">Hello world</div>
</div>
```

---

As per current HTML, you can use [`.next()`](https://api.jquery.com/next/)

> Get the immediately following sibling of each element in the set of matched elements. If a selector is provided, it retrieves the next sibling only if it matches that selector.

```
jQuery(function($) {
   $('.test').click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
       $(this).hide().next().show();
   })
});
```

Comment: I think `$(this).hide().next().show()` is better and shorter.

Comment: Is it possible to hide another element when click this same link?

Comment: @CssSY, Yes you can

Comment: How can I do that? I followed your fist code block.

Comment: @CssSY like `$(selector).hide();` like `$('.hello').hide();`

Comment: Oh thanks. I'm bit new to jquery. Can you update with your answer with hiding this "upload-from-pc" div also? That would be great.

Answer (score 1):

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="fetch-from-link">
 <a href="#" class="test" onClick="$(this).parent().hide();$('.hello').show();">
  Fetch from link
</a>


</div>
<div class="hello" style="display: none; ">Hello world</div>
```

You must move the div outside because you are hiding the div containing your "Hello world" text.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="fetch-from-link">
 <a href="#" class="test" onClick="$(this).hide().siblings('.hello,.second-class,.third-class').show();">
  Fetch from link
</a>

<div class="hello">Hello world</div>
</div>
```

You are hiding the whole `div` containing both the elements. Hide link only.

Comment: If I want to use hide another two, three elements, Do I need to repeat the code changing classes?or is  there any combined way of doing this?

Comment: you can specify multiple classes at a time for all the sibling elements that you want to hide

Comment: Great! Is it possible to hide another element when click this same link?

Comment: yes it is possible. Just replace "this" with selector for that element